# How to get the value of a span in a modal and put it in another span in another modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reveal.js, modal-window

I'm new in using modals. I just wanted to ask how can I get a value of a span in a modal window with an id of "span1" and put its value to another modal window that has also a span with an id of "span2"? thanks.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ is there for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('#span2').text($('#span1').text());
```

Although you'll obviously need to do this under some event, such as the click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
var span1val = $('#span1').html();
$('#span2').html(span1val);
```

Comment: +1. Actually html() method is the condition for what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery's [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html)

```
 $('#span2').html($('#span1').html());
```